# Riemann Zeta Function equation

Tags: riemann-zeta

So I'm a amateur mathematician and I was working with the Riemann Zeta Function and I was able to proof this identity. So I'm just wondering if this has already been proven before.

[image]
For S>0

So I realize my use of a sum might be kind of ambiguous, its trying to illustrate the polynomial that represents the sum of each consecutive power.
For example the  sum of m^2=n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/2

Comment: What is $n$ supposed to be?

Comment: You are integrating harmonic numbers. Check out the wiki